# What ethernet driver do I need?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ethernet

I was originally using wifi, and I installed Hamachi to allow for a more direct hosting option for my game servers, but now I no longer needed it, and uninstalled it. However now, I have no Ethernet adapter (it doesn't appear in my list of adapters).

I have attempted to search for the correct drivers, but so far no luck. I have:

- Detect hardware changes in the Device Manager
- Searched for Drivers online (automatic)
- Looked for the appropriate drivers using intel online
- Searched for drivers online manually, though I am uncertain as to what exactly I am searching for.

I am at work at the moment, so I am unable to give all the necessary information for my PC, but I will be able to get that all later. For now:

- PC: All-in-one Asus Desktop
- OS: Windows 7 Home 64-bit

**EDIT**

Ethernet adapter properties:

[image]

Currently installed adapters

[image]

I have found (what I believe to be) the driver i need, however, before the process even starts, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: most of the time, ethernet drivers are automatically installed, but if not, desktop restore disk should contain them. if you have an intel CPU, then you can probably install the Chipset Drivers from intel to resolve the issue. if all else fails, install somthing like speccy, and check your nic's make and model, so you can find them online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the PCI vendor and device string from Device Manager. Right click the unknown device->properties->details.  Then use the dropdown to pick Hardware IDs.  You will see something like **PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8168&SUBSYS_E0001458&REV_06**

In this instance, the Vendor ID is 10EC and the device ID is 8168.

You can then use the site www.pcidatabase.com to start narrowing it down.  It may not tell you who sold the card, but it will at least tell you the chipset, and from there you can figure it out.

Comment: Great! This works for me.

Comment: The website no longer works...  is solving this problem no longer possible?

Comment: https://devicehunt.com